Unencrypted Linux drive and it still shows as encrypted after login
I am using Linux Mint and at times when I restart my computer, I boot it up, put my password to unencrypt the drive, login and my home folder is still showing as encrypted with the "Access-Your-Private-Data" file.
Yesterday it did it and I restored my system to a previous snapshot. Today I really want to know why it's doing it.
When I configured Linux Mint I chose the option to encrypt my drive and my home folder.

It could be a mistyped password, damage to the drive, etc. Research LUKS, Linux Unified Key Setup issues, e.g., https://warlord0blog.wordpress.com/2021/08/10/luks-password-problems/
